# Ubuntu post install tool

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

I need to automate an ubuntu post-installation system configuration. I'm install ubuntu often, and after each installation I need to run some commands on ubuntu. I.E.

```
sudo apt-get install git
git config --global alias.co checkout
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Is there any specific software or I need to write just a `.sh` file?

Comment: Why not write a sh file?

Comment: It's not a sexy way. But I think about `.sh`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to automate your post Install tasks there is a very nice tool already available. It is called ubuntu-post-install. You can find it in the below ppa.

https://launchpad.net/~thefanclub/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-after-install

This Tool has a GUI where you can select the software you want to automatically install. I use it a lot really Nice tool. Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but there is not the programs I want to install.

Comment: What is it that you want to install ? Please can you let us know !!

Comment: I wrote a list of commands at the top

Comment: I think you are looking at creating a shell script for automating post Installation.. by all means you can write a shell script for the Job !!